# Customizing jquery ui Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is it possible to completely customize [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/home) datepicker to match your website theme, including position of header, buttons and images. If it is possible, than what should be the approach. How to go about it? I want to (almost) redesign it completely. What are other possible options?

I have tried to change/customize it a bit using jquery [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) but it does not allow to change buttons, images or overall design of the date picker box.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify it. just go through the this link and download the files .  i customized datepicker header, content, selected style. n other options  . [JqueryUi-Datepickr](http://jqueryui.com/download/?themeParams=?ffDefault%253DGill%252BSans%252CArial%252Csans-serif%2526fwDefault%253Dbold%2526fsDefault%253D1.2em%2526cornerRadius%253D4px%2526bgColorHeader%253D9b0303%2526bgTextureHeader%253D07_diagonals_medium.png%2526bgImgOpacityHeader%253D35%2526borderColorHeader%253D2c4359%2526fcHeader%253De1e463%2526iconColorHeader%253De1e463%2526bgColorContent%253Dffffff%2526bgTextureContent%253D01_flat.png%2526bgImgOpacityContent%253D75%2526borderColorContent%253Daaaaaa%2526fcContent%253D2c4359%2526iconColorContent%253Dc02669%2526bgColorDefault%253De25050%2526bgTextureDefault%253D07_diagonals_small.png%2526bgImgOpacityDefault%253D50%2526borderColorDefault%253D93c3cd%2526fcDefault%253D333333%2526iconColorDefault%253Dffffff%2526bgColorHover%253D323ed2%2526bgTextureHover%253D07_diagonals_small.png%2526bgImgOpacityHover%253D75%2526borderColorHover%253D999999%2526fcHover%253D212121%2526iconColorHover%253D454545%2526bgColorActive%253Ddb4d48%2526bgTextureActive%253D07_diagonals_small.png%2526bgImgOpacityActive%253D40%2526borderColorActive%253Dff6b7f%2526fcActive%253Dffffff%2526iconColorActive%253Dffffff%2526bgColorHighlight%253Dffff38%2526bgTextureHighlight%253D10_dots_medium.png%2526bgImgOpacityHighlight%253D80%2526borderColorHighlight%253Db4d100%2526fcHighlight%253D363636%2526iconColorHighlight%253D88a206%2526bgColorError%253Dff3853%2526bgTextureError%253D07_diagonals_small.png%2526bgImgOpacityError%253D50%2526borderColorError%253Dff6b7f%2526fcError%253Dffffff%2526iconColorError%253Dffeb33%2526bgColorOverlay%253Df7f7ba%2526bgTextureOverlay%253D11_white_lines.png%2526bgImgOpacityOverlay%253D85%2526opacityOverlay%253D80%2526bgColorShadow%253Dba9217%2526bgTextureShadow%253D01_flat.png%2526bgImgOpacityShadow%253D75%2526opacityShadow%253D20%2526thicknessShadow%253D10px%2526offsetTopShadow%253D8px%2526offsetLeftShadow%253D8px%2526cornerRadiusShadow%253D5px)

or  alternativily you can visit [JqueryDatepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) n select theming tab.

this is the general mark up for date time picker. you can customize it

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
   <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
      <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
      <a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a>
      <div class="ui-datepicker-title">
         <span class="ui-datepicker-month">January</span><span class="ui-datepicker-year">2009</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th>
         ...
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody><tr>
         <td class="ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month "> 1 </td>
         ...
      </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content">
      <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Today</button>
      <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all">Done</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how did you do that. There is only option either to include date picker or not.

Comment: @UmerHayat you can select for datepicker, if you need or you can select for all other widgets. if it matches your application need

Comment: I have already done that. Now after including date picker, I need to customize it to match my theme. For example, I want to add an extra row on top of it, change image of "next" and "Prev", change the size and shape of the calender boxes etc.

Comment: @UmerHayat i think you need to do manually. by using above general markup on your own