# Custom styling jQuery UI's Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Is it possible to style jQuery UI's Datepicker with custom styles but keep the same functionality? For example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is. You will need to roll your own theme.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616898/customizing-jquery-ui-date-picker/10616992#10616992

Comment: Yes but theme roller cannot do exact same style, and its like original datepicker but different colors this is not what i want.

Comment: use a different datepicker (the one in the screenshot?)

Comment: i made it in html & css but the javascript?

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can with a little CSS overwriting. For example, I changed the following:

```
.ui-datepicker td {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 0;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
}
```

And immediately got something a lot more similar to what you are wanting.

Comment: mm tried it, yes its kind of similar but how to style month bar?

Comment: thank you! i will alter it more and hope get the result that i want :]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, which is quite similar to your image.
`!important` needs to be included to overwrite JavaScript.
Thanks to Alex above, I have included his answer.

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {border: solid #FFF!important;border-width: 1px 0 0 1px!important;}
.ui-datepicker td {border: 1px solid #CCC!important;padding: 0!important}
.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr th span {font-size: 12px!important;text-transform: uppercase!important;}
.ui-widget-header {background: #2d2d2d!important;border: 0!important}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {background: #2d2d2d!important; color: #fff!important;font-size: 15px!important;}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {background-image: none!important;}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {margin-top: 4px!important;}
#ui-datepicker-div {padding: 0;width: 325px!important;}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default, .ui-button, html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover, html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg,#e2e2e2,#eeeeee)!important;}
.ui-state-default {font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold!important;}
.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {padding: 0!important;text-align: center!important;}
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {width: 33%!important;padding-left: 22px!important;}
.ui-datepicker th {padding: 0em .3em 0.2em!important;}
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus, .ui-button:hover, .ui-button:focus {
    background: #3fadb6!important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #4ea3ab, inset 0px 0px 20px #2a97a0!important;
    color: #ffffff!important;}
.ui-datepicker table {margin: 0!important;}
.ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev {border: 0!important;}
/*Right Arrow*/
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {width: 0!important;height: 0!important;border-left: 10px solid white!important;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent!important;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent!important;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent!important;
}

/*Left Arrow*/
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span {width: 0!important;height: 0!important;border-right: 10px solid white!important;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent!important;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent!important;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent!important;
}
```